# C# - Evento MouseLeave não funciona em Label diferente

Tags: c#, winforms, eventos-do-mouse

Criei dois Label's com nomes diferentes e criei dois métodos para cada Label responsável por fazer um evento de **Hover** meio que parecido no CSS **(foi só uma comparação**).

```
//Evento responsável por fechar a aplicação através do Label "X".
private void closeApplicationClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{    
    this.Close(); //Responsável por fechar a aplicação por meio do "X".            
}  

//MouseEvent para sublinhar o Label "Cadastrar um novo usuário"
private void newUserOnMouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Atribuição de uma nova propriedade "Underline" para que o Label "Cadastrar um novo usuário" seja sublinhado.
    newUser.Font = new Font(newUser.Font.Name, newUser.Font.SizeInPoints, FontStyle.Underline);
}

//MouseEvent para remover o sublinado do Label "Cadastrar um novo usuário"
private void newUserOnMouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Atribuição de uma nova propriedade "Regular" para que o sublinhado seja removido do Label "Cadastrar um novo usuário"
      newUser.Font = new Font(newUser.Font.Name, newUser.Font.SizeInPoints, FontStyle.Underline);
}

//MouseEvent para sublinhar o Label "Esqueci a minha senha"
private void ForgotPasswordOnMouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Atribuição de uma nova propriedade "Underline" para que o Label "Esqueci a minha senha" seja sublinhado.
      forgotPassword.Font = new Font(forgotPassword.Font.Name, forgotPassword.Font.SizeInPoints, FontStyle.Underline);
}

//MouseEvent para remover o sublinado do Label "Esqueci a minha senha"
private void ForgotPasswordOnMouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Atribuição de uma nova propriedade "Regular" para que o sublinhado seja removido do Label "Esqueci a minha senha"
      forgotPassword.Font = new Font(forgotPassword.Font.Name, forgotPassword.Font.SizeInPoints, FontStyle.Regular);
}
```

Os dois métodos estão com nomes diferentes, tentei trocar a variável do `object sender` mas não funcionou, até o `EventArgs e` eu troquei pra outra variável e também não funcionou.

Eu achei que ia funcionar perfeitamente porém só o **Esqueci a minha senha** está funcionando perfeitamente.

Eu já **setei** os eventos `MouseEnter` e `MouseLeave` nas propriedades do Label, porém não funciona.

Confira essa imagem:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: É pra desktop... Ou melhor dizendo **Windows Forms Application**, não é aplicação WEB.

Comment: Onde você está adicionando os events de MouseEnter e MouseLeave nos respectivos linklabel?

Comment: Não seria melhor usar "MouseOver"?

Comment: @Patrick eu achei também que ele funcionava meio parecido com o **CSS** kkk mas não deu.

Answer (score 0):

**Israel**, sugiro centralizar num método a ação de sublinhar (ou estilizar de maneira geral), assim, o que funcionar para um, funcionará para outros, além é claro, de manter o código mais limpo para revisões:

```
forgotPassword.MouseEnter += (sender, e) => EstilizaLink(sender, e, "sublinhar");
```

ou

```
forgotPassword.MouseLeave += (sender, e) => EstilizaLink(sender, e, "naoSublinhar");
```

E o método `EstilizaLink(...)`:

```
void EstilizaLink(object sender, EventArgs e, string acao)
{
    var label = ((Label) (sender));
    var estilo = (acao == "sublinhar" ? FontStyle.Underline : FontStyle.Regular);

    label.Font = new Font(label.Font.Name, label.Font.SizeInPoints, estilo);
}
```

Obviamente o método pode vir a trazer outras características. De qualquer forma, testei aqui e não tive problemas em sublinhar e remover o sublinhado no mouseEnter e mouseLeave.

Comment: Como assim centralizar em apenas um método? De qualquer forma não estará utlizando um método pra setar o evento e outro para o EstilizaLink?

Comment: Conceitualmente falando, "estilizar" pode ser guardado em um método só ou, dependendo do volume inclusive, de uma classe estática com métodos estáticos (uma vez que esta não precisaria ser instanciada). Você chegou a testar? Para mim funcionou, coloquei em 2 labels.

Comment: Eu tentei fazer, porém o Visual Studio acusa um erro na variável sender quando eu chamo o forgotPassword.MouseLeave += (sender, e) => EstilizaLink(sender, e, "naoSublinhar");

Comment: Qual erro? Lembrando que **forgotPassword.MouseLeave += (...)** deve ser chamado no .cs e deve ter acesso ao escopo da função _void EstilizaLink(...)_ que acabamos de criar.